# Creating a custom comparable Tree-like data structor in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, tree, operator-overloading, incomplete-type

I have a type `struct Type_Specifier` which I want to represent an immutable tree like structure that I can compare. I have the following code to illustrate what I want:

```
#include <vector>

struct Parameter_Specifier;
struct Type_Specifier
{
    explicit Type_Specifier(void* tag = nullptr, std::vector<Parameter_Specifier> parameters = {})
        : tag(tag), parameters(parameters) { }

    Type_Specifier(const Type_Specifier&) = default;
    Type_Specifier(Type_Specifier&&) = default;
    Type_Specifier& operator=(const Type_Specifier&) = default;
    Type_Specifier& operator=(Type_Specifier&&) = default;
    ~Type_Specifier() = default;

private:
    // Points to an arbitray memory location (whose lifetime is not managed by this type)
    void* tag;
    std::vector<Parameter_Specifier> parameters;

public:
    static bool operator ==(const Type_Specifier& left, const Type_Specifier& right)
    {
        if (left.tag != right.tag)
            return false;
        else if (left.parameters.size() != right.parameters.size())
            return false;
        else for (std::size_t i = 0; i < left.parameters.size(); i++)
        {
            if (!(left.parameters[i] == right.parameters[i]))
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    static bool operator <(const Type_Specifier& left, const Type_Specifier& right)
    {
        if (left.tag < right.tag)
            return true;
        else if (left.parameters.size() < right.parameters.size())
            return true;
        else if (left.parameters.size() > right.parameters.size())
            return false;
        else for (std::size_t i = 0; i < left.parameters.size(); i++)
        {
            if (left.parameters[i] < right.parameters[i])
                return true;
            else if (right.parameters[i] < left.parameters[i])
                return false;
        }

        return false; // left == right
    }   
};

struct Parameter_Specifier
{
    explicit Parameter_Specifier(Type_Specifier type = Type_Specifier(), std::vector<char> value = {})
        : type(type), value(value) { }

    Parameter_Specifier(const Parameter_Specifier&) = default;
    Parameter_Specifier(Parameter_Specifier&&) = default;
    Parameter_Specifier& operator=(const Parameter_Specifier&) = default;
    Parameter_Specifier& operator=(Parameter_Specifier&&) = default;
    ~Parameter_Specifier() = default;

private:
    Type_Specifier type;
    // Arbitrary data (not a 'string' or sequence of 'characters')
    std::vector<char> value;

public:
    static bool operator ==(const Parameter_Specifier& left, const Parameter_Specifier& right)
    {
        if (!(left.type == right.type))
            return false;
        else if (left.value.size() != right.value.size())
            return false;
        else for (std::size_t i = 0; i < left.value.size(); i++)
        {
            if (left.value[i] != right.value[i])
                return false;
        }

        return true; // left == right
    }

    static bool operator <(const Parameter_Specifier& left, const Parameter_Specifier& right)
    {
        if (left.type < right.type)
            return true;
        else if (left.value.size() < right.value.size())
            return true;
        else if (left.value.size() > right.value.size())
            return false;
        else for (std::size_t i = 0; i < left.value.size(); i++)
        {
            if (left.value[i] < right.value[i])
                return true;
            else if (left.value[i] > right.value[i])
                return false;
        }

        return false; // left == right
    }
};
```

However it of course will not compile, probably due to `struct Parameter_Specifier` being incomplete, and the operators '<', and '==' being undefined.

My question is this:
***How Can I modify the above types to make it compile and work properly? (and efficiently?)***

Notes:

- The purpose of this type is to be used in a two-way map structure to be able to map between `struct Type_Specifier` and `std::size_t` (i.e. it needs to be both a key type and a value type)
- I will define the other comparison operators '!=', '>', '>=' and '<=' based on my definitions of '==' and '>', I have omitted them here for brevity
- I am pretty sure that `a == b` is equivalent to `!(a < b) && !(b < a)`
- The order of comparison isn't really relevant, as look as it is a *strict weak ordering relation*
- I would like the `Type_Specifier` type to follow the RAII idiom
- The `Paramater_Specifier` type is only used for children of `Type_Specifier` and nowhere else
- I only whish to use the C++ standard library

I was considering making `Type_Specifier::parameters` an `std::vector<Parameter_Specifier*>` but then I would have to manually manage allocation, in `Type_Specifier`, which would cause obvious problems as `Parameter_Specifier` is incomplete there.

Comment: _"but then I would have to manually manage allocation"_ No, you can use a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Parameter_Specifier>>`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ that doesn't help at all, it just created a new error `function "std::unique_ptr<_Ty, _Dx>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty, _Dx>::_Myt &) [with _Ty=Parameter_Specifier, _Dx=std::default_delete<Parameter_Specifier>]" cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function` without fixing any,
I also have no idea how I would write an expression that gives me a (non-empty) `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Parameter_Specifier>>`

Answer (score 1):

You have problems with relational operators.

1) for `operator==()`, you have two alternative: (a) a method of the class/struct with *one* parameter (the left argument, `*this`, is implicit), that can't be `static`, or (b) an external function (`friend`, usually) with *two* parameter. You have mixed the two alternative and have made the method `static`. I strongly suggest alternative (b): external function. So (take in count that there is an `operator==()` for `std::vector`) `operator==()` for `Type_Specifier` could be

```
friend bool operator== (const Type_Specifier & left,
                        const Type_Specifier & right)
 {
   return           ( left.tag == right.tag )
          && ( left.parameters == right.parameters );
 }
```

For `Parameter_Specifier` could be

```
friend bool operator== (const Parameter_Specifier & left,
                        const Parameter_Specifier & right)
 {
   return     ( left.type == right.type )
          && ( left.value == right.value );
 }
```

2) same thing for `operator<()`. Moreover, if "`left.tag < rigth.tag`" is `false`, I think you should verify that isn't `true` that `left.tag > right.tag`. My suggestion (but with different behaviour; caution) for `Type_Specifier` is

```
friend bool operator< (const Type_Specifier & left,
                       const Type_Specifier & right)
 {
   return    ( left.tag < right.tag )
          || (    ( left.tag == right.tag )
               && ( left.parameters < right.parameters ) );
 }
```

For `Parameter_Specifier`, my suggestion (with different behaviour; caution) is

```
friend bool operator< (const Parameter_Specifier & left,
                       const Parameter_Specifier & right)
 {
   return    ( left.type < right.type )
          || (    (left.type == right.type )
               && (left.value < right.value ) );
 }
```

3) having `operator==()` and `operator<()` others relational operator are straightforward. For `Type_Specifier`

```
friend bool operator!= (const Type_Specifier & left,
                        const Type_Specifier & right)
 { return ! (left == right); }

friend bool operator> (const Type_Specifier & left,
                       const Type_Specifier & right)
 { return (right < left); }

friend bool operator<= (const Type_Specifier & left,
                        const Type_Specifier & right)
 { return ! (right < left); }

friend bool operator>= (const Type_Specifier & left,
                        const Type_Specifier & right)
 { return ! (left < right); }
```

For `Parameter_Specifier`... well... change `Type_Specifier` with `Parameter_Specifier`.

P.s.: sorry for my bad English.